# Accessing The Request Via Route Closures

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

In this route below, what is the ***user()*** function?

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::get('user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an instance of the authenticated user. It's the same as `auth()->user()`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user

Answer (score 1):

A global helper returning the user making the request. Identified through `auth:api`